# How to sync async and await Tasks?

Tags: c#, synchronization, asynchronous

With threads you could use Semaphore, mutex,  ManualResetEvent, etc... to sync a shared data, how do you accomplish the same thing with tasks? Essentially, if I have shared data between different tasks that run on the thread pool with `Task.run()` or that resume on the thread pool on a random thread after an async event, how would I sync them up if they share data?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: With semaphore specifically, just use waitasync on the semaphoreslim.

Comment: For Tasks, use [WhenAll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The question body mentions shared data between tasks, so I doubt this is as simple as `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Have you tried the lock-free collections? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/when-to-use-a-thread-safe-collection ; otherwise, have you considered designing to not require shared data?

Comment: What occurrence do the tasks need to wait for?

Answer (score 3):

You need a lock that allows you to `await` it rather than block. This functionality is offered by the [SemaphoreSlim](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-5.0) class.

```
SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

async Task HandleLockedResource() 
{
    await _semaphore.WaitAsync();

    try
    {
        await DoSomethingWithLockedResource();
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

See also [How to combine async with locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269412/how-to-combine-asynchrony-with-locking) and [What is the best practice using async in lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60282318/what-is-the-best-practice-using-async-method-in-lock)